# Javascript alert on change (showing error)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to alert the selected option from select, but it is not alerting.

It is showing an error:

> {   "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of
>   null",   "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",   "lineno": 18,
>   "colno": 43 }

I tried:

```js
function selectOption() {
  var x = document.getElementById("item1").value;
  alert("You selected: " + x);
  if (option == "Item") {

    return true;
  } else if (option == "ZZ2017TF11A1") {
    return true;
  } else if (option == "ZZ2017TF11A2") {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

```html
<select class="country" name="item1" onChange="selectOption()">
  <option value="Select Item">Item</option>
  <option value="ZZ2017TF11A1">Shirt</option>
  <option value="ZZ2017TF11A2">Pant</option>
</select>
```

**How to Solve it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do this with pure `JavaScript`(without `jQuery`), you can try this. I've made some changes to make the code more understandable.

```
function selectOption() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("item1");

  // get selected option value
  var selectedOptVal = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
  alert("You selected: " + selectedOptVal);

  // get selected option text
  var selectedOptTxt = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].text;

  if (selectedOptTxt == "Item") {
    return true;
  } else if (selectedOptTxt == "ZZ2017TF11A1") {
    return true;
  } else if (selectedOptTxt == "ZZ2017TF11A2") {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Add the `id` field inside the select tag.

```
<select class="country" id="item1" name="item1" onChange="selectOption()">
  <option value="Select Item">Item</option>
  <option value="ZZ2017TF11A1">Shirt</option>
  <option value="ZZ2017TF11A2">Pant</option>
</select>
```

Also, please concern about your **nested-if** section. Since it's not usable.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `document.getElementById("item1")` , add `id="item1"` in the `<select>` element.

Comment: Thank you so much for sorting out the mistake. But still, it is having an `error:{
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: option is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 20,
  "colno": 3
}`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$('#item1').val()`

```
function selectOption() {
    var x = $('#item1').val();
    var option = $('#item1 option');
    alert("You selected: " + x);

    if (option == "Item") {
        return true;
    } else if (option == "ZZ2017TF11A1") {
        return true;
    } else if (option == "ZZ2017TF11A2") {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

`#item1` refers to the ID, you only specified the `name` in the HTML.

```
<select id="item1" class="country" name="item1" onChange="selectOption()">
  <option value="Select Item">Item</option>
  <option value="ZZ2017TF11A1">Shirt</option>
  <option value="ZZ2017TF11A2">Pant</option>
</select>
```

You also forgot to define `option`, which you can do by `$('#item1 option')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function selectOption(element) {
  var x = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
  alert("You selected: " + x);
  var option = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;

  if (option == "Item") {

    return true;
  } else if (option == "ZZ2017TF11A1") {
    return true;
  } else if (option == "ZZ2017TF11A2") {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

```html
<select class="country" id="item1" onChange="selectOption(this)">
  <option value="Select Item">Item</option>
  <option value="ZZ2017TF11A1">Shirt</option>
  <option value="ZZ2017TF11A2">Pant</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function selectOption(){
$(this).html(alert("You selected:"+ $("#item1").val()));//for selected option value
$(this).html(console.log("You selected:"+ $("#item1 option:selected").text()));//for selected option text
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="item1" class="country" name="item1" onChange="selectOption()">
  <option value="Select Item">Item</option>
  <option value="ZZ2017TF11A1">Shirt</option>
  <option value="ZZ2017TF11A2">Pant</option>
</select>
```